# How to call event handler through UI thread when the operation is executing into Task? (C#)

Tags: c#, multithreading

Does it exist any approach to execute event handler through UI thread (WinForms) when the raising code is executing into Task (not UI)?

There is **Threading.Timer** 's callback, its code is called from ThreadPool always. The callback can raise an event. However ThreadPool do its handlers also. I subscribe on the event through UI thread:

```
    //UI
    (Action<string>) MyEvent += (string result) => 
{ MyInput.Text += String.Format("server: {0}", result); }; //changes GUI

    //The timer's callback, not UI:
    MyEvent(result); //exception...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell your Task to continue on the UI thread. Since you started the task from the UI thread, it will capture the context. You can do this to tell it to continue on that captured context:

```
// Lets say task is your task that you started so tell it to continue like this
Task UITask= task.ContinueWith(() =>
{
    // Do UI update here 
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Oh and if you use System.Windows.Forms.Timer instead, then the events will be fired on the UI thread automatically.

Comment: Also if a task is called not through UI thread, before it we could assign to global var the UI-associated TaskScheduler (calling 'TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()' being in UI thread) to get access to this scheduler later.